# How can I randomly sample from the set of NP Complete problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, randomness

I'd like to create some program that can keep spitting out verification algorithms.

My verification algorithms take two inputs: problem instance, and solution (both encoded in binary), and output True or False. Every verification algorithm my program returns needs to satisfy the following criteria:

- It terminates in polynomial time (in terms of size(problem instance)+size(solution))
- The problem of: "Given a problem instance input, find a solution input that results in the verification  algorithm returning True" is NP-Complete.

It seems like "sampling uniformly" from this space has the same problem of sampling uniformly from the set of integers, so I'm okay with a biased sampling method. However, I'd like every NP-Complete problem to have a non-zero chance of being sampled. Because verification programs are countable, this should be doable.

One idea would be to have some initial set of NP-Complete problems, and consider things like [problem input=(problem A instance, problem B instance, ...) solution input=(problem A solution, problem B solution, ...))] and then AND the individual verifiers. You could even go more general and consider boolean functions on the individual problem's verifiers. This fails because I'm not aware of any "basis" of NP-Complete problems that by composition can give all NP-Complete problems, so we'd be missing some problems that can't be formed as compositions of our problems.

Is this studied somewhere? Or how would I do this? I'm having trouble finding the words for it.

Comment: We don't know nearly enough about the structure of NP-complete problems to have any chance of designing such a sampling procedure. For starters, we don't even know whether $P=NP$.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden but it is computable. Consider: enumerate through all (polytime reductions from your instance to sat, polytime reductions from sat to your instance, verification algorithms, proofs in ZFC that those reductions are correct with respect to verification algorithm). Enumerate in increasing order wrt the sum of lengths of each piece. For each tuple, check the proof. If it works, return that instance, if it's wrong, continue. 

If P=NP is independent of ZFC some reductions might be lacking a proof, and this will miss things, but otherwise it should work. However it's too slow.

Comment: Assuming the [Berman-Hartmanis conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berman%E2%80%93Hartmanis_conjecture), it would suffice to be able to sample polynomial-time bijections, i.e., to be able to sample over all algorithms $f$ such that $f$ is a bijection and both $f,f^{-1}$ can be computed in polynomial time.  I don't know how to do that, either, though; and apparently the Berman-Hartmanis conjecture is suspected to be false, which doesn't help, either.